# How to use one button to add scores for different integers (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, button, tags, switch-statement

Right now i have a purple and red score. I would like to use the 1 and 2 buttons to add the score for the colors. I know how to do this by creating just a sets of buttons to the specific color but doing this again and again will create problems. So what I am trying to do is if purple is selected and if and only if 1 is pressed then the total score of purple will = 1. I guess what I am trying is perform a switch statement for the buttons.

Before purple/red button is pressed. 
[image]

After purple/red button is pressed. 
[image]

```
  import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var purpleScore = 0
    var redScore = 0


    @IBOutlet var plus1: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet var plus2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var addRed: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var addPurlple: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var totalScorePurple: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var totalScoreRed: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        plus1.isHidden = true
        plus2.isHidden = true



    }

    @IBAction func enteringRed(_ sender: Any) {
        plus1.isHidden = false
        plus2.isHidden = false


         }
    @IBAction func enteringPurple(_ sender: Any) {
        plus1.isHidden = false
        plus2.isHidden = false


               }
    @IBAction func plus1(_ sender: Any) {
    }

    @IBAction func plus2(_ sender: Any) {
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you just want one `@IBAction` function for the two buttons?

Comment: no i want to use both @IBAction buttons to add either 1 or 2 for the selected color.

Comment: How do you determine the "selected" color?

Comment: But what triggers `enteringRed` or `enteringPurple`?  You can only tap one button at a time. Do you want the red/purple to toggle on/off or perhaps act like radio buttons where you can only select one at a time?

Comment: @Paulw11 he meant he got 2 button as red and purple, and another 2 as 1 and 2, if red is pressed and 1 got pressed, redScore+=1, something like that i suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly as the comment above, this should work

Create 2 Bool for red and purple to see weather they are checked or not, this is easiest way, else you can just check the redButton color got changed (if it does) or `.selected = true`

```
var redChecked = false
var purpleChecked = false
@IBAction func enteringRed(_ sender: Any) {
   redChecked = !redChecked
   //change color etc..
}

@IBAction func enteringPurple(_ sender: Any) {
   purpleChecked = !purpleChecked
   //change color etc..
}
@IBAction func plus1(_ sender: Any) {
   if redChecked {
      redScore+=1
   }
   if purpleChecked {
      purpleScore+=1
   }
}

@IBAction func plus2(_ sender: Any) {
   if redChecked {
      redScore+=2
   }
   if purpleChecked {
      purpleScore+=2
   }
}
```